Lights and shades around a dot
Is there a way to add lights and or shades around a dot to get a close result to the following image using geom_point?

I have thought about creating a gradient for each dot but I don't know how to implement it since each dot should have a single value.
Found the following topic where the author kind of achieved to get 3 colors per dot but I don't know the strucure of his data and it seems that he plotted each dot 3 times.
R ggplot increase points by size and by color for same variable
Reproducible example
##### Initiating data
dfDot <- data.frame(value=1,
                    group="A")

##### Display plot
plotDot <- 
  ggplot(data=dfDot, aes(x=group, y=value)) + 
  geom_point(size=80) + 
  theme_dark() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())


Following MrFlick answer
Using both geom_point and with_blur from MrFlick proposition, could achieve something close to the image
##### Import blur library
library(ggfx)

##### Initiating data
dfDot <- data.frame(value=sort(rnorm(120)),
                    group=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=40))

##### Defining colors
myColors <- c("#7be5d7", "#e57b7b", "#e5d57b")

##### Display plot
  ggplot(data=dfDot, aes(x=group, y=value, color=group)) + 
  with_blur(
    geom_point(size=8), sigma=20  
  ) + 
    geom_point(size=3, alpha=0.05) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=myColors, guide="none") + 
  theme_dark() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())



Do you just want to add some blur to the point? You can do that with the ggfx library. For example
library(ggfx)

dfDot <- data.frame(value=1,
                    group="A")

##### Display plot
  ggplot(data=dfDot, aes(x=group, y=value)) + 
  with_blur(
    geom_point(size=80), sigma=20  
  ) + 
  theme_dark() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())



Thank you! This is one part of what I would like to achieve. Do you know if there is a way to play on fill colors so that there is some kind of gradient around the core/kernel?

Add more points with different colors and sizes. But the image you showed basically just looks like blur. I'm not sure what other colors you are trying to add.

I am going to play with different points. I just had in mind that I can add several geom_point rows
